# How do I track and store the position of a current closest class instance relative to another class instance (again...)

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

In my UFO shooter game I would like the player to be able to spike the closest UFO, to insure chaos and awesomeness. Lol. Anyways, I can't seem to figure out how to store the closest current UFO (or *drone*, as I call them in the code)...

Here are all of the functions and classes for the game. (kinda messy, I know, but I'll probably revise it later)

```
var score = 0;
var bullets = [];
var drones = [];

var keys = [];
keyPressed = function () {
    keys[keyCode]=true;
};
keyReleased = function () {
    keys[keyCode]=false;
};

var player = function (x,y) {
    this.x = 25;
    this.y = 440;
    this.w = 15;
    this.h = 20;

    this.xvel = 0;
    this.yvel = 0;

    this.accel = 0.2;
    this.frict = 0.08;

    this.isShooting = false;

    this.update = function () {
        this.leftGun = this.x-11-this.xvel;
        this.rightGun = this.x+20-this.xvel;
        if (this.isShooting) {
            this.gunsY = random(this.y,this.y+7);
        } else {
            this.gunsY = this.y+3;
        }

        if (keys[LEFT]) {
            this.xvel -= this.accel;
        }
        if (keys[RIGHT]) {
            this.xvel += this.accel;
        }
        if (keys[UP]) {
            this.yvel -= this.accel;
        }
        if (keys[DOWN]) {
            this.yvel += this.accel;
        }

        if (this.xvel > 0 || this.xvel < 0) {
            this.xvel -= this.xvel * this.frict;
        }
        if (this.yvel > 0 || this.yvel < 0) {
            this.yvel -= this.yvel * this.frict;
        }

        fill(255, 255, 255);
        //rect(this.x-this.w/2,this.y + 5,this.w,this.h);
        triangle(this.x,this.y+this.h-this.xvel+this.yvel,this.x+this.xvel+7,this.y,this.x+15,this.y+this.h+this.xvel+this.yvel);

        fill(0,0,255);
        //ellipse(this.x+7,this.y+14,7,7);
        rect(this.leftGun,this.gunsY,4,15);
        rect(this.rightGun,this.gunsY,4,15);

        this.x += this.xvel;
        this.y += this.yvel;
    };
};
var p1 = new player();



// verify status
var active = function(obj){
    return obj.x>0 && obj.y<height+100;
};
var bulletActive = function(blt){
    return blt.x>0 && blt.x < width && blt.y>0 && blt.y<height+20;
};

var droneArt = function(){
    var zz = this.z/2;
    var dam = map(this.h, 0, 100, 0, this.z);
    if (this.h<0){
         this.x = -100; 
         score+=(80-this.z);
         return;
    }
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(this.x-zz, this.y-zz-10, this.z, 4);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(this.x-zz, this.y-zz-10, dam, 4);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(this.x,this.y);
    //rotate(r);

    fill(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(0,0,this.z,this.z);

    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(0,0,this.z-this.z/1.8,this.z-this.z/1.8);

    for(var i = 0; i < 360; i += 45){
        rotate(i);
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.z-this.z/1.6,0,this.z-this.z/1.15,this.z-this.z/1.15);
    }
    //r++;
    popMatrix();
    this.y += 0.4;


    /*
    for(var i = 0; i < 360; i += 45){
        rotate(i);
        fill(255,0,0);
        ellipse(this.z-this.z/1.6,0,this.z-this.z/2,5);
    }
    */
};

// drone object
var drone = function(x, y){
    return {
    x:x,
    y:y,
    z:20 + floor(random(2)) * 20,
    h:100,
    draw:droneArt };
};

// bullet object
var bullet = function(x, y, s, id){
    return {
        x:x, y:y, s:s, z:3,
        draw: function(){
            if (id==="canon"){
                this.y -= 7;
                fill(255, 97, 97);
                ellipse(this.x+2,this.y+9,this.z*3,this.z*4);
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(this.x,this.y+9,this.z*3.2,this.z*4.2);
            } else {
                this.y -= 14;
                fill(102, 102, 255);
                rect(this.x-this.z/2, this.y, this.z, this.z+10);
            }
        }
    };
};

// collision test
var kill = function(obj){
    var test = function(blt){
        if (dist(obj.x, obj.y, blt.x, blt.y)<(obj.z+blt.z)/2){
            obj.h -= blt.s;
            blt.x = -100;
        }
    };
    return test;
};

var r = 0;
var drawDrone = function(drn){
    //r += 0.2;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(drone.x,0);
    rotate(r);
    drn.draw();
    popMatrix();

    bullets.forEach(kill(drn));
};

var drawBullet = function(blt){
    blt.draw();
};

var ufo;
var distance;
var minUFO = 10000;

var drones = [drone(100, 100), drone(200, -100), drone(300, 0)];

/*minUFO = minUFO === null || t > minUFO ? t : minUFO;*/

var minUFO = 9999999999;
var findNearestDrone = function () {
    for(var i=0; i < drones.length; i++) {
        var ufo = drones[i];

        var po = dist(ufo.x,ufo.y,p1.x,p1.y);

        if (po < minUFO) {
            minUFO = po;
        }

        fill(255, 0, 0);
        stroke(255,0,0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        line(ufo.x,ufo.y,p1.x+8,p1.y);
        noStroke();

        //println(ufo + " drone " + i);

        text(minUFO,30,100);
    }
};
```

It turns out that, unlike what I expected; but logically, the minUFO only ever gets smaller. Instead of storing the position of the closest current UFO, it seems to store the smallest distance between the UFO and the player ever recorded in the session. Which, turns out, isn't what I want either. Anybody know how to store the current closest drone's position? Not just the distance like I have it right now, but its actual position. Thank you, and I'm sincerely sorry for my incredible ability to take a millennia to get to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `var minUFO = 9999999999;` inside the `findNearestDrone` function. That way the variable is reset every time you call the function and is no longer influenced by the previous smallest distance.

Next, similarly to the way you store the minUFO, you can use a variable that keeps track of either the ufo itself or the index that is associated with the nearest ufo (so far).

I've modified your code with both options:

```
//initiate vars outside function
var nearestUFO;
var nearestIndex;

var findNearestDrone = function () {

    //initiate var that tracks min distance inside function
    var minUFO = 9999999999;

    for(var i=0; i < drones.length; i++) {
        var ufo = drones[i];

        var po = dist(ufo.x,ufo.y,p1.x,p1.y);

        if (po < minUFO) {
            minUFO = po;

            //store the current nearest ufo / index 
            nearestUFO= ufo;
            nearestIndex= i;
        }

        fill(255, 0, 0);
        stroke(255,0,0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        line(ufo.x,ufo.y,p1.x+8,p1.y);
        noStroke();

        //println(ufo + " drone " + i);

        text(minUFO,30,100);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it! I would vote your answer up... but I just joined so my rep isn't high enough. :'(

Comment: No problem. If it was useful, you could consider ['accepting'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.